# Displaying JavaScript for loop in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm trying to display a countdown on my web page using a JavaScript function containing a for loop.  I'm unsure of what the correct way to call it is.
It's supposed to display within my page something like:

count: 19
count: 18
count: 17
count: 16
count: 15
... and so on.

So far I can only get "count: 19" to show up.  On a different variation I got the entire count to show up but once the button was clicked my page would disappear (go white) and the count would be displayed.  There's a bit more HTML and CSS to the page but I've cut out the non-relevant parts.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you!  Here's my code:

```js
function forLoopCountDown() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "count: " + i + "<br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Count Down</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Count Down Page</h1>
  </header>
  <h2>Click on the button below to do a count down</h2>
  <button onclick="forLoopCountDown()">count down 1 using for loop</button>
  <p id="count">&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are overwriting the "count" element's value constantly, you need to append the string instead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `setInterval`, and get rid of `for` loops all together. Set a counter, increment the counter every `setInterval` call, then kill the interval after the counter gets too high.

If you want to count DOWN from 20 to 0, you need to use `i--` instead of counting up with `i++`.

```
<header>
  <h1>Count Down Page</h1>
</header>
<h2>Click on the button below to do a count down</h2>
<button id="timerBtn">count down 1 using for loop</button>
<p id="count"></p>

document.getElementById("timerBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  var i = 20;
  var interval = setInterval(function(){
    i--;
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML += "count: " + i + "<br>";
    if (i == 0)
    {
      clearInterval(interval)
    }
  }, 250)
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6p9u0ks/1/

## EDIT: If delay is unneeded, and for loops are required:

The idea is to start the counter at `i = 20`, then count down to zero. Use the above HTML, but replace the JS with the following:

```
document.getElementById("timerBtn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  for (var i = 20; i > 0; i--) //Take note of this line
  {
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML += "count: " + i + "<br>";
  }
})
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/e6p9u0ks/2/

Comment: I forgot to mention that this is for a homework assignment which requires me to use for loops.

Comment: If you dont need a delay, then that does simplify things. I'll edit in a second.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why only 19 shows up is because of your counter

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
```

So, we start with 0, and add 1 to `i` until `i == 19`, and each time the loop is run, you are overwriting the `<p id="count">&nbsp;</p>` with a new value, so you see the final value, which is `count: 19`

So, you want to increment down, not up

```
 for (var i = 19; i >= 0; i--)
```

Also, you want to create a new `p` tag each time.

```
var para = document.createElement("p");
var node = document.createTextNode("Count: " + i);
para.appendChild(node);
```

```js
function forLoopCountDown() {
  for (var i = 19; i > 0; i--) {
    var para = document.createElement("p");
    var node = document.createTextNode("Count: " + i);
    para.appendChild(node);
    document.body.appendChild(para);
  }
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Count Down</title>

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Count Down Page</h1>
  </header>
  <h2>Click on the button below to do a count down</h2>
  <button onclick="forLoopCountDown()">count down 1 using for loop</button>
  <p id="count">&nbsp;</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML += "count: " + i + "<br>";
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "count: " + i + "<br>";
```

this way you wont overwrite the innerHTML property every iteration.

Also u are counting up, use `i--`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use setinterval function to call your function after each second.

```
var i = 0
setInterval(function ()
 {
  for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML + = "count: " + i + "<br>";
  }
},1000)
```

I have not tested the code, but once you get your function correct, setinterval function will make sure it runs after every second

Comment: Close, but this will run the for loop every second, never ending.

Comment: Yeah, but you can use stop interval if you want or use variables to never call setinterval depending upon the problem. Just like you did :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to modify this line of your code...

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = "count: " + i + "<br>";
```

...to look like this

```
document.getElementById("count").innerHTML += "count: " + i + "<br>";
```

Comment: This is the exact duplicate of my answer :)

Comment: oh yeah, didn't see that :p